# How to execute something on the main thread from my unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am developing a .NET class library written in C# which calls into some unmanaged C++ code. I am using Task in C# to execute things in worker threads but I am not sure how to call something in managed code's main thread from my C++ unmanaged code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What type of app is your main? Off the top of my head the most direct way seems to be to pass the main form's window handle to the unmanaged side and then do a SendMessage from unmanaged to invoke the main window function, but this obviously assumes a GUI application.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, since I am developing a class library, the caller might not be a GUI application at all.